# Using Vert.x `AuthenticationHandler` from vertx-web, we hit the authentication provider for every call?

Tags: java, rest, oauth-2.0, authorization, vert.x

I'm using Vert.x for my web service, where a part of it required authorization. I've set an `AuthenticationHandler` (using the OAuth2 implementation from `vertx-auth-oath2`) to listen on the protected paths (lets say `"/*"`) and it is correct called, sends a redirect to the authentication provider, which redirects back and then correctly to the real handler. This works fine.

But the next time we call the protected endpoint - it does the whole thing again. I see that in the abstract `AuthenticationHandlerImpl` class it checks if the context already has a `user()` and if so - will not run the actual auth handler, which is the behavior I need - but it obviously doesn't happen because every call is a new request with a new `RoutingContext`.

What is the "correct" way to retain the `User` object across requests, so that the auth handler will be happy?

I'm guessing it has something to do with session storage but I've never used that - up until now I was using a custom "API key" style solution, and I'm trying to do this "The Right Way(tm)" in this new project.

I'm using the latest Vert.x 4.3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need CookieHandler and SessionHandler to store and handle session with user. This will work out of the box with provided vertx-auth-oath2.

Here is a simple example to get you started:
https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/web-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/web/auth/Server.java

Comment: The example is for Vert.x 3, while I'm using 4. Both `AuthProvider` and `UserSessionHandler` are not supposed to be used anymore. But I got it working by registering a new session handler created using `SessionHandler.create(ClusteredSessionStore.create(vertx));`.

Comment: I found the following caveats: (1) the session handler must be registered before the auth handler; (2) If the auth handler applies only to some of the paths, the session handler must be applied to the same paths and additionally to the callback URL that is registered internally in the authentication handler using the `setupCallback()` method.

Comment: The usage of the session handler also causes the auth handler to do a proper 302 redirect from the OAuth callback URL to the original URL, otherwise it does an internal redirect (that the browser doesn't see) and that can lead to all sorts of messes.

Comment: There is a 4.x branch with the same example but it does not differ much. https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/4.x/web-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/web/auth/Server.java

Comment: Also yes, route order is important, same applies for body handlers or any other handlers.

Comment: You can omit CookieHandler that I proposed as SessionHandler will do it by default, The session handler handles the creation of session cookies and the lookup of the session, so you don’t have to do that yourself.

Comment: Its interesting that the `master` branch is for the older major version .